# iframe onload is triggered twice for target form submission

Tags: html, iframe

I'm using an iframe to upload images with an ajax feel, and I use unload to trigger a javascript function that loads a preview and hide the loading gif, but my problem is that the function is loading ONCE when the page loads, and ONCE when the form is submitted. I can't think of another handler that would work? Or is there another alternative?

```
<form id="profileForm" method="post" action="build/parsers/upload-photo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload" onsubmit="startPhoto();">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="profileSelect" onchange="document.getElementById('profileForm').submit();" />
    <button id="profileUpload" onclick="document.getElementById('profileSelect').click(); return false;" type="submit">Upload</button>
 </form>

 <iframe name="upload" id="upload" onload="stopPhoto();"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correctly triggered twice, because the iframe loads twice. As you've noticed, it loads again when you post to it. You can make it work as expected by setting the `onload` handler of the iframe in the `onsubmit` handler of the form. This way your function will trigger only in the iframe load after form submission.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Is it because the iframe isn't being submitted... the form is? So on submit is never triggered for the iframe.

Comment: As I said, you use the `onsubmit` handler **of the form**, to bind the `onload` handler **of the iframe** to your `stopPhoto()` function.

Comment: This solution does not work for me even if I add the `onload` handler in the form submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the iframe onload event triggered/fired as expected on form submit in Chrome, but in IE11 on form submit it was triggering twice, as well as triggering on page load.  Check and see if it solves your issue?

[iframe onload in chrome vs IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476771/iframe-onload-in-chrome-vs-ie11)